# Is there any way i can use to build realm structure as well as data?

Tags: ios, realm

I am trying to work with [Realm DB](https://realm.io) for iOS.

I am using the below tools at the moment.

1. [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/app/realm-browser/id1007457278) by Realm.io that helps me edit all data in Realm DB
2. [Realm object editor](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/RealmObjectEditor) from that helps me edit the realm structure.

This doesn't help me to have a single realm DB and related objects to be used in Xcode project.

Comment: Tool or library requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I need to prepare data for application. I create another target DataGenerator and form filled defaul realm object in AppDelegate didFinishLaunch:

```
 NSString *fileName = @"Activities";


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"json"];
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers error:&error];

NSMutableArray *sessionDays = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonDataArray) {
    SessionDay *sessionDay = [[SessionDay alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
    [sessionDays addObject:sessionDay];
}

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    [realm addObjects:sessionDays];
}];
```

print this file path at my mac

```
    NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

Copy that file into my primary target bundle. In primary target AppDelegate copy that file from bundle to application folder:

```
  NSString *preLoadRealmPath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"realm"];

NSError *error;
NSURL *url = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].fileURL;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:preLoadRealmPath toPath:url.path error:&error];
```